# Get Headers from SQL Table

Tags: sql-server-2012, table, export, bcp

I am looking for a way to dynamically get the headers from a table without having to write them (select 'header1' as "header1"...., 'header50' as "header50" from MyTable)
It doesn't work above a certain number of columns, and/or the fixed limit of characters in a query

The goal is to export the headers and the data from the table to a text file or an excel file with a BCP command.

Can you help me out, please ?

Comment: There is a stored procedure  `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` . Please read about this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: How about querying [information_schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6215760/503046)?

Comment: @vonPryz I was looking at that, but I do not know how to get them in rows rather than one column

Comment: When you say “get the headers from a table”, do you mean get the actual column names OR do you actually mean “header1” is for the first column, “header2” is for the second columns, etc?

Comment: @ScottHodgin Hi, I mean the actual column names, and I took as an example header1 is the name of the first columns etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `xp_cmdshell` and `Powershell` is an option (rather than `BCP`), you could achieve your goal as follows:

```
--Demo setup to create and load a table with some data
SET NOCOUNT ON
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[CUSTOMER];
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CUSTOMER](
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StreetAddress] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CUSTOMER] ([CustomerID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [PhoneNo], [StreetAddress], [City], [OrderID]) VALUES (13579246, N'David', N'Casey', N'dcasey@gmail.com', 12826363, N'34 Bray Rd', N'Dublin', 94724274)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CUSTOMER] ([CustomerID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [PhoneNo], [StreetAddress], [City], [OrderID]) VALUES (16579946, N'Donal', N'Smith', N'dsmith@gmail.com', 13826563, N'78 Ballybrack Rd', N'Dublin', 14724274)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CUSTOMER] ([CustomerID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [PhoneNo], [StreetAddress], [City], [OrderID]) VALUES (17579946, N'Steve', N'Reidy', N'sreidy@gmail.com', 13827563, N'22 Conna Rd', N'Cork', 64724274)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CUSTOMER] ([CustomerID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [PhoneNo], [StreetAddress], [City], [OrderID]) VALUES (18579946, N'Michael', N'Yule', N'myule@gmail.com', 14827563, N'44 Blasket Rd', N'Kilkenny', 44424274)
GO
```

---

A *possible* downside to this approach is because ConvertTo-CSV automatically surrounds output columns with double quotes. The follow script handles the elimination of ALL double quotes.  This could be problematic if your data actually contains double quotes.

```
--The solution
--The output goes to C:\Test\test.txt
--Make sure that the parameter value for -ServerInstance below is equal to the Server Name
--of the SQL Server instance you want to access.  The example below is using a single period 
--which indicates the default instance on the computer where the Powershell script is actually running.

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(4000)
set @cmd = 'powershell.exe "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance . -Query ''Select * from Test.dbo.customer'' | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t"  | % {$_ -replace ''""'',''''} | Out-File (''C:\Test\test.txt'') "' 
print @cmd
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

---

Note that the `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet allows you to specify a Delimiter.  If you don't provide that parameter, the default is a comma (as represented by the output below.

Results in C:\Test\test.txt:

```
CustomerID,FirstName,LastName,Email,PhoneNo,StreetAddress,City,OrderID
13579246,David,Casey,dcasey@gmail.com,12826363,34 Bray Rd,Dublin,94724274
16579946,Donal,Smith,dsmith@gmail.com,13826563,78 Ballybrack Rd,Dublin,14724274
17579946,Steve,Reidy,sreidy@gmail.com,13827563,22 Conna Rd,Cork,64724274
18579946,Michael,Yule,myule@gmail.com,14827563,44 Blasket Rd,Kilkenny,44424274
```

Here is an example where I'm using *backtick t* (`t) to export a tab delimited file.

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(4000)
set @cmd = 'powershell.exe "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance . -Query ''Select * from Test.dbo.customer'' | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t"  | % {$_ -replace ''""'',''''} | Out-File (''C:\Test\test.txt'') "' 
print @cmd
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the reply. I tried it, but my output file is empty, I don't know why. I replace the name of the data base, the name of the table and the output path, the rest is identical

Comment: Perhaps you could post exactly what you ran?  Maybe we could spot a flaw.  Also, try bring up regular Powershell and running the command there.  Do you see any errors?  You may need to remove the `no_output` from the xp_cmdshell to actually see any errors.

Comment: This is what I ran : 
`DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(4000)
set @cmd = 'powershell.exe "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance . -Query ''Select * from TESTCONSOLE.dbo.grand_livre'' | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace ''""'',''''} | Out-File (''C:\Users\FR019673\Documents\Mission\TESTCONSOLE_TECA_Déc2018\SQL\Résultats\test.txt'') "' 
print @cmd
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd,no_output`

Comment: It says Something about an error during the connection : (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Impossible d'ouvrir une connexion à SQL Server) [Impossible to open a connexion to SQL Server]

Comment: Are you running this command on the actual server where SQL Server is installed.  The `-ServerInstance` parameter in your example points to the local default instance (indicated the the single dot (.).  Are you using a named instance?  Make sure you are pointing to the correct SQL Server instance.

Comment: The adress of it ?
No, I am accessing it, but not running the script from it.

Comment: The error you're getting suggests that you are not using the correct value for the-ServerInstance parameter.  The single dot after that parameter indicates the default instance on the computer where the script is running.  Replace that single dot with the appropriate SQL Server instance.  If you were to connect to that SQL Server instance from SQL Server Management Studio, what `Server Name` would you use?

Comment: Hi ! I replaced the dot with my server name, and then with localhost, and it worked, both times !
Thank you !

One last thing, Is there a way to chose the separator used in the csv file ?

Comment: @AmandineFAURILLOU - yes, you can specify a `-Delimiter` parameter.  I updated my answer to show how that is specified.

Answer (score 1):

To generate such a list, let's combine information_schema and row to column transpose. The sample code uses SO's Tags table like so,

```
declare @sq nvarchar(max)  -- Results

;with cols as(  -- CTE to select columns whit data types
select
    col = column_name + ' ' + data_type +
    case 
        when CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL then ', '
        when CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 then '(max), '
        else '(' + CONVERT(varchar(4), CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) + '), '
    end
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'Tags' -- Table name goes here
)
select @sq = (select distinct     --  Transpose rows to single column
names = STUFF((select ' ' + col
    from cols
    for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
from cols as t)

select @sq = LEFT(@sq, LEN(@sq)-1)  -- Remove the trailing comma
select @sq  -- Display the results
```

Result:

```
Id int,  TagName nvarchar(150),  Count int,  ExcerptPostId int,  WikiPostId int
```

Comment: I had gotten this far, without the data types (I don't need them). I would need to export the result of the query to a file and then merge that file with the export of the data, and I don't know how to get the result of the header query into a file